# Is there a way to save an intermediate output in Tensorflow to a file?

Tags: debugging, save, tensorflow

I have a conv net that does a bunch of things.

The inference code looks something like this:

```
conv0_feature_count = 2
with tf.variable_scope('conv0') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 1, conv0_feature_count], stddev=5e-2, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [conv0_feature_count], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv0 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
```

And so on and so forth followed by max pooling, etc.

I would like to be able to save conv0 to a file for inspection.  I know that tf.Print would print the values in the console, but it is a big tensor.  Printing the value makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TensorFlow doesn't have any public operators that make it possible to write a tensor to a file, but if you look at the implementation of [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) (in particular the [`BaseSaverBuilder.save_op()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/952a447010cdb4ed507ff29c28f999ba43e959f3/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L233) method), you will see that it includes an implementation of an op that can write one or more tensors to a file, and it is used to write checkpoints.

**CAVEAT:** The following solution relies on an internal implementation and is subject to change, but works with TensorFlow r0.10rc0.

The following snippet of code writes the tensor `t` to a file called `"/tmp/t.ckpt"`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops

t = tf.matmul(tf.constant([[6, 6]]), tf.constant([[2], [-1]]))

save_op = io_ops._save(filename="/tmp/t.ckpt", tensor_names=["t"],
                       tensors=[t])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(save_op)  # Writes `t` to "/tmp/t.ckpt".
```

To read the value you can use `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader()` as follows:

```
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader("/tmp/t.ckpt")
print reader.get_tensor("t")  # ==> "array([[6]], dtype=int32)"
```

Comment: do you know if there are plans to add writers?  otherwise, I can add and send in a pr to the GitHub repo.  It would be really useful for debugging.

Comment: I'm not aware of any concrete plans, although the `tf.train.Saver` is currently being revised (to use a more efficient checkpoint format), so it might be possible to piggy-back the implementation on that effort. Feature requests are welcome!

Comment: what about using image_summary?

Comment: AFAIK, the `tf.image_summary()` is limited to serializing 4-D tensors that represent batches of images. In principle the summary protocol buffers could be extended to support arbitrary tensor data, and that would also be a worthwhile feature request.

Comment: that's probably ok now.  I can just reshape to a rank 4 tensor and then reshape back for visualization.  thanks!

Comment: also, do you know if the team takes PR from non google people on the GitHub repo?  I imagine there is an internal version, and code push is only one way?  internal to external only?

Comment: External PRs are more than welcome! There's a two-way code push between the internal and external versions.

Comment: This still doesn't write the output of the layer, just the values right?