# Tensorflow: Save tensors in graph to file (or image)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I currently have a complex set of operations that iteratively create images and feed them to processes to be used.  This is part of a very huge and complex graph.  I would like to make sure that those images are being created correctly.

Normally for debugging, we have `tf.Print`, which creates a no-op with a side-effect of printing to the screen.

Is there either 
a) Some way I can store a very large intermediate tensor to a file? 
b) Some way to specifically store intermediate tensor images to file (or the screen)?

Obviously, if I have an evaluated numeric tensor this is no problem as I can visualize it using matplotlib's `imshow`, but as a symbolic tensor it's not so obvious how to do this.

I could save a bunch of intermediate tensors to evaluate with `sess.run`, but the way my code is architected, it will be very hard to manually access and gather those all.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025340/is-there-a-way-to-save-an-intermediate-output-in-tensorflow-to-a-file ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save tensors with spatial correlations (image like tensors) in tensorflow is via [`tf.summary.image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image). Check out the [tensorboard tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) for how it all fits together, but the crux is like the following:

```
tf.summary.image("img", img)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
for i in range(num_iters):
    summary = sess.run(merged)
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

Then start up tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir logs
```

Then go to `localhost:6006` in a browser to see the summaries.

The downside to this approach is that you don't have fine grain control over what slice you see unless you explicitly specify (e.g. `tf.summary.image("img", img[...,10])`)

Comment: To clarify, is that second test_writer supposed to be train_writer?